# Decorator is not a function - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I feel like I'm following the docs on this for Query/QueryList, but I'm still getting the error "(SystemJS) decorator is not a function."

Am I defining the Query and QueryList correctly?

```
import { Directive, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, Output, HostBinding,
    EventEmitter, ElementRef, ContentChildren, ViewChildren,
    Query, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { DropdownMenuInterface } from './dropdown.interface';
import { DropdownToggleInterface } from './dropdown.interface';
import { dropdownService, NONINPUT} from './dropdown.service';

@Directive({selector: '[dropdown]'})
export class Dropdown implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    ......

    // index of selected element
    public selectedOption:number;
    // drop menu html
    public menuEl:ElementRef;
    // drop down toggle element
    public toggleEl:ElementRef;

    dropdownMenuList: QueryList<ElementRef>;

    constructor(public el:ElementRef,
       @Query('dropdownMenu') dropdownMenuList: QueryList<ElementRef>) {
     }

     public set isOpen(value) {
     this._isOpen = !!value;

   .....
```

}

Comment: I believe that this problem is related to SystemJS configuration, not your code.

Answer (score 0):

Both `Query` and `QueryList` are not decorators, but types (or classes anyway).

I think `@ViewChildren` sets up a private property, to be updated according to the `Query` passed to it (I think `Query` is the type of object you need to send to one of the querying decorators (`@ViewChildren`, `@ViewChild`, `@ContentChild` and `@ContentChildren`).

And `QueryList` is the type of the property if you've used one of the `Children` (not `Child`) variants of the querying decorators.